# Accessing each entries of DataFrame and replacing them in a better way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This question is an additional question of my previous question that I posted. What I would like to do is to replace DataFrame's string value to its first initial string. For example,

```
s = pd.DataFrame({'A':['S12','S1','E53',np.NaN], 'B':[1,2,3,4]})

s.A.fillna('P', inplace=True)
```

This will give me a Dataframe

```
   A  B
0 S12 1
1 S1  2
2 E53 3
3 P   4
```

But then, I would like to change the string values of column 'A' to ['S', 'S', 'E', 'P'], which is their first character. What I did is following,

```
for i, row in s.iterrows():
    if len(row['A']) > 1:
        s['A'][i] = row['A'][0]
```

and I got this warning.

```
/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:3:         SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-    docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  app.launch_new_instance()
/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:7: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

I understand that this is a non-preferred way, but what exactly I am doing inefficiently and what would be the preferred way? Is it possible to do it without converting them to numpy array?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) by `str[0]`:

```
s['A'] = s['A'].fillna('P').str[0]
print (s)
   A  B
0  S  1
1  S  2
2  E  3
3  P  4
```

Comment: Downvoter, if there's something wrong with my answer, please let me know, so I can correct it. Thanks.

Comment: @ScottBoston - Somebody downove without reason First another answer and then my too :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply method to trim text in each row. Also to not get `SettingWithCopyWarning:`  warning you have to use `.loc` and `copy()`

```
s = s.copy()

s.loc[:,"A"] = s.A.apply(lambda x : x[0])

print(s)

    A   B
0   S   1
1   S   2
2   E   3
3   P   4
```

Comment: Please let me know what's wrong instead of down voting so that I can help you with it

Comment: Not me, check [this](https://snag.gy/ItSLMT.jpg). And no idea why you get downvote :(

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the 'SettingwithCopyWarning' because of the way you are assigning back to your dataframe.  If you wish to use your "non-preferred" way, then you can avoid this warning message by using `.loc`:

```
for i, row in s.iterrows():
    if len(row['A']) > 1:
        s.loc[i,'A'] = row['A'][0]
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  S  1
1  S  2
2  E  3
3  P  4
```

**NOTE:** You can get more info on index chaining in the Pandas docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy).  Also, there are some good SO posts on 'SettingWithCopyWarning'.